How to test the connection from AWS to an on-premise, private API?

I have an API running in an on-premise K8s cluster.
I plan to use AWS for load balancing/access/auth/etc to expose this API to the public internet.
To forward requests from AWS to my API, I am experimenting with both AWS Site-to-Site VPN and making the on-prem API visible to just AWS.
I can confirm that the API is visible from outside the K8s cluster and within my local network with a ping or curl command.

What is the equivalent for within AWS? Is there a suitable AWS product (eg Lambda) within which I can execute arbitrary curl or ping commands to test the AWS -> LAN connection?
